# Slow boot and dns doesn't work

Tags: ubuntu, boot, dnsmasq

I don't understand what happened because i didn't change anything in system for quite a long time. Now system boots too slow and when it's booted - dns requests don't work. I can ping remote hosts by ip but can't request them by names. Here's what i've found in `syslog`:

```
Dec 20 18:05:12 my-pc NetworkManager[1003]: <error> [1387548312.403516] [nm-dns-dnsmasq.c:402] update(): dnsmasq owner not found on bus: Could not get owner of name 'org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq': no such name
Dec 20 18:07:15 my-pc NetworkManager[2699]: <warn> failed to allocate link cache: (-10) Operation not supported
Dec 20 18:22:57 my-pc NetworkManager[2699]: <warn> DNS: plugin dnsmasq update failed
```

Also for some reason now I can mount usb flash drives only through console. I use Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: Well, now it works. I can't tell why but here are steps that i've done: I've added static ip settings for my eth0 with google dns servers to /etc/network/interfaces and when I tried to restart networking service my computer hanged. When I rebooted and removed those lines from file, dns requests started to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here an extract from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Dnsmasq

> Note that the package "dnsmasq" interferes with Network Manager which
>   can use "dnsmasq-base" to provide DHCP services when sharing an
>   internet connection. Therefore, if you use network manager (fine in
>   simple set-ups only), then install dnsmasq-base, but not dnsmasq. If
>   you have a more complicated set-up, uninstall network manager, use
>   dnsmasq, or similar software (bind9, dhcpd, etc), and configure things
>   by hand.

I would suggest to check your config and see if this case applies to you.

Comment: Can't figure out why it interferes if I didn't even install system updates. I've got only `dnsmasq-base` installed. And I have never changed any of it's configs.

Comment: Do you have an similar error at boot time ? `NetworkManager[1316]: <warn> DNS: plugin dnsmasq update failed`

Comment: Updated my last comment. Yes, I have this warning in syslog.

Comment: So you are in this case. Try to apply what's described in the provided  link in answer

Comment: If you mean I need to remove network manager and install dnsmasq, I can't do it, because I have no access to repositories.

Comment: Why don't you have access to repositories ?

Comment: Well, because i have no dns.

Comment: dnsmasq seems to be already installed on your system. If you don't really need it. If you have a standard setup (no shared internet connexion for sample) you can remove dnsmasq.

Comment: there's `dnsmasq-base` installed in my system as a dependency for `networking-manager`, not `dnsmasq`

Comment: what about your `/etc/resolv.conf` file ?

Comment: didn't change it, everything works now without it. Saved my actions in comment to question.

Comment: Normal : you have moved to static ip so now your dnsmasq (dnsmasq-based) dhcp manager is bypassed. Just as explained in the link provided ;) glad it works. But you are not using dhcp anymore. If it is suitable for you it is ok for me, if not, you are now ready to go further following steps in the link provided.

Comment: Actually I tried to explain that i removed those lines from `interfaces` because network-manager didn't work properly with those lines. My computer even hanged when I tried to restart `networking` service.